# Why is the use of IConfiguration a bad thing in Azure Functions Dependency Injection

Tags: azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection) it states:

> Injection of IConfiguration can lead to unexpected behavior.

Without much explanation of what that means. Does anyone know:

What scenarios this happens in?

What is the behavior?

Why is it such a bad thing?

Comment: It's actually worse than it first looks. Later in the same document it states : 

> The following services are safe to take as a dependency in your application: 
> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration Singleton Runtime configuration

Answer (score 0):

**IConfiguration** is just use to ***retrieve the Configuration settings from your Function App in your code***.Refer below:-

The **IConfiguration** might show unexpected behaviour if you use it as dependency injection and want to fetch the setting in Runtime, Or If you misconfigured your setting in Azure Function app. Thus as per the document, Using a custom setting set in Function helps and using **IConfiguration** along with it will make the behaviour more efficient.

> **Injection of `IConfiguration` can lead to unexpected behavior. To learn more about adding configuration sources, see [Customizing configuration sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#customizing-configuration-sources).**

In the Customizing configuration sources link, When using **`IConfiguration method`** to override the App settings by using a custom **`appsettings.json`** file instead of Azure Function's configuration settings. Some unexpected behaviour may happen. Also, If your application depends on the latest Configuration settings and your Injected **IConfiguration** setting is different, Some issue will happen while running your Application.

I have tried retrieving setting from my Function App using with **IConfiguration** method in **Http_Trigger Function**:-

My setting in **Environment Variable:-**

```
MySetting:This is a setting value
```

[image]

[image]

My **Function.cs:-**

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyNamespace.Startup))]

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            IConfigurationRoot config = builder.ConfigurationBuilder
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            builder.ConfigurationBuilder.AddConfiguration(config);
        }

        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            // Register options
            builder.Services.Configure<MyOptions>(builder.GetContext().Configuration.GetSection("Values"));
        }
    }

    public class MyOptions
    {
        public string MySetting { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyFunction
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly IOptions<MyOptions> _options;

        public MyFunction(IConfiguration configuration, IOptions<MyOptions> options)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _options = options;
        }

        [FunctionName("MyHttpTrigger")]
        public IActionResult Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Value from IConfiguration: {_configuration["MySetting"]}");
            log.LogInformation($"Value from IOptions: {_options.Value.MySetting}");

            return new OkObjectResult("Check logs for settings values");
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use IOptions to get your Function app settings value.

**Local Output:-**

[image]